# ssh X11forwarding not working , but only on debian8

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

I recently installed Debian 8 on my workstation , which before ran Ubuntu 15.04 , but after Debian 8 came into my life, I have not succeeded in running ssh with X11forwarding.

case is:

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04, and when I login to that server from my laptop ( also Ubuntu 14.04 ), I have no problem getting X11forwarding working, but if I try to login from my Debian8 workstation, I will get this error when trying to run xterm (output is from ssh -X serverip )

```
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0
```

A `ls` shows that the file exists

```
$ ls -la /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 18 17:53 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

In the server's sshd_config i have the following options enabled

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes ( i have tried both yes and no here )
X11DisplayOffset 12
```

and in my ssh_config on my Debian8, I have the following lines enabled

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

As I see it with a 'ssh -vv -X serverip' all x11 debug message are the same both on my working laptop, and nonworking are the same, and ~/.Xauthority get created on the server when I login

The following environment variables are set when I log into the server from my laptop ( some variables are omitted )

```
SSH_CLIENT=1.1.1.1 59061 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qHuaV5m5QO/agent.32572
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LOGNAME=xxx
SSH_CONNECTION=1.1.1.1 59061 2.2.2.2 22
DISPLAY=localhost:12.0
```

the following environment variables are set when I log into the server from my debian8 workstation (some variables are omitted)

```
SSH_CLIENT=3.3.3.3 59148 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-fwG6aBA4he/agent.32763
SSH_CONNECTION=3.3.3.3 59148 2.2.2.2 22
DISPLAY=localhost:12.0
```

All tests are done with ssh -X serverip, and firewall is disabled.

Note: if I login to the server from my laptop via the Debian workstation, X11forwarding works fine

Comment: Why is your DISPLAY set to 12?

Comment: I have also tried X11DisplayOffset 10 , makes no difference , this examples the X11DisplayOffset is just 12 by coincidence.